# Finding right multiple choice answers

Tags: python

Dont know if this is the right place to ask but i want to write code to take the given answers to a multiple choice question(a,b,c, or d) and the overal score, 0-8, from multiple people and find any answers that can be known for certain. I just need a little idea of how to start this problem. right now i just have hardcoded lists for the answers and whether or not they are right (based on an assumption that if everyone agrees its correct)

```
Andrew = [5, ["B", True], ["C", False], ["C", False], ["B", False], ["D", False], ["A", True], ["C", False],
      ["A", False]]
David = [4, ["B", True], ["C", False], ["B", False], ["C", False], ["D", False], ["A", True], ["B", False],
         ["D", False]]
Adam = [4, ["B", True], ["C", False], ["D", False], ["C", False], ["B", False], ["A", True], ["C", False], ["A", False]]
Glendon = [4, ["B", True], ["A", False], ["B", False], ["D", False], ["D", False], ["A", True], ["C", False],
           ["A", False]]
Ellen = [5, ["B", True], ["C", False], ["B", False], ["C", False], ["D", False], ["A", True], ["D", True], ["D", False]]
Andrew = [4, ["C", False], ["C", False], ["A", False], ["A", False], ["D", False], ["A", True], ["D", True],
          ["A", False]]
```

Comment: So you want to guess if an answer is right based on if everyone said it's true or false?

Comment: not really if everyone has the same answer i would assume it is right but i want to try guessing based on how people's answers compare and how many they got right

Comment: You are touching on a couple of pretty hard subjects here, you have hard constraints (The answers must add up to the scores received) and statistical likelihood (Probability that Andrew got question 4 right given that he only got half of the questions right or the probability that the answer to question 2 is "C" given that 5/6 students gave that answer).

Depending on how precise you want your answer to be, there are a number of different solutions.  Mind if I ask where this problem comes from? It could help narrow down the best solution.